# Can Google Earth Engine return the 12 digit HUC associated with a lat/long or address

Tags: google-earth-engine

The EPA has an implementation called How's my water. [https://mywaterway.epa.gov/](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2020-08/documents/attains_how_to_access_web_services_2020-08-31.pdf)

As I understand it, here is kind of how their application works.

1. Input -> lat/long or address in the USA
2. The application gets the 12 digit HUC associated with the location e.g. "080801030109"
3. Using the HUC and a webservice called ATTAINS the application gets the assessment Unit Id e.g. "LA060801_00"
4. Using the assessment Unit Id and ATTAINS, the application returns useful data e.g. "the name of the nearest waterbody e.g. "Vermilion River-From headwaters to LA-3073 bridge"

ATTAINS -> [webservice ATTAINS](https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2020-08/documents/attains_how_to_access_web_services_2020-08-31.pdf)

So my question is how do I approach step 2 above?
Can Google Earth Engine return the 12 digit HUC associated with a lat/long or address?

here's the code so far and the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to step 2 using:

```
// 1: input
var lat = -99.33;
var lon = 42.77;
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([lat, lon]);

// 2: get HUC associated with the location
var HUC = table.filterBounds(point);
var HUCdigit = ee.Feature(HUC.first()).getString('huc12')
```

[Example code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aab8c6c522d05022ec1482b9a3276d4c)

Comment: I have a follow up question. Now i know google earth engine can give me the result i want, how would 'my own' web application take advantage of this. Can i use google earth engine like a web service? Deploy/save my function on the server and call it when i need it?